# Any online community sharing Simulink models for computer vision?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, simulink, matlab-cvst

As a newbee for Simulink, I am fascinated with the model-based design of algorithms in Simulink. So naturally, I am looking for what others have done with Simulink in computer vision area. Of course, I know Mathworks provided with many examples and exchange site with more but I am searching for more models. Is there any online community to share simulink models?

Comment: Well, It seems that this question is about to be closed. But I am also wondering about this question. Like UML and as its ad suggested. Simulink is visual programming environment. So claims that this question is not related to programming baffles me.

Comment: @Dima do you expect this question to be reopened now it is retagged?

Comment: @rene I don't expect anything. I've just tagged it, because it fits the category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well Peter Corke provides a handy pair of Matlab/Simulink toolboxes for [Robotic Control](http://petercorke.com/Robotics_Toolbox.html) and [Machine Vision](http://www.petercorke.com/Machine_Vision_Toolbox.html). It might not be exactly what you need, but I have found them extremely useful.